# Changing service console default gateway affect VM connectivity?

Tags: vmware-esx

if I change the default gateway of the ESX 4 service console virtual machines connectivity will be affected? Virtual machines must not be disconnected as they are in production environment

Thank you all for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But as with any change like this, test it out on a non-critical environment first, and perform the actual cut-over during the period where there's least impact if the services do go down.

Always plan it like it's going to fail.

Traffic for the VMs themselves flow over a seperate VM Network definition. Which could potentially be bound to the same network adapter, but they don't use the service console for traffic.

Comment: Agree with Chris, from a VM perspective a vSwutch is a purely L2 function so yo changing a L3 property won't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the SC IP or gateway won't affect the VMs.  For example, we've changed the IP of our SCs before, causing the host to be disconnected in vSphere, but a quick re-connect brings it back in, with no guest interruption.